# How do I determine the default project selected in the Visual Studio Package Manager Console in Powershell?

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, package-managers

I am writing some Powershell scripts that are going to be in a Nuget package, which I will then run from the Package Manager Console. These scripts will run all the tests within the project that is selected in the "Default Project" drop down, in the Package Manager Console. My question is, how do I determine (in Powershell) which project is currently selected in the Package Manager Console?

[image: Package Manager Console Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are a number of useful commands available to you in the Package Manger Console, one of which is:
>
> **Get-Project** which on its own will give you the name of the Default project in the Package Manager Console. However:
>
> **Get-Project -All** 
>   Produces a list of all the projects in the currently loaded solution.

http://www.edcourtenay.co.uk/musings-of-an-idiot/list-referenced-nuget-packages-from-the-package-manager-console

Comment: `Get-Project -All` would be really helpful if it returned.. all projects.  It only returns some (skips a database project for instanceR.

Comment: Linked site seems to be down.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the default project in Package Manager Console by using `$proj`.  You can verify the name of the project by typing `write-host $proj.Name` in the Package Manager Console and hitting Enter. This will display the default project name in the Package Manager Console. Hope this helps!

Comment: I've tried doing `write-host $proj` and `write-host $proj.Name` in the package manager console, but nothing is printed.